# Permission denied when running Python script from Vim

Tags: python, vim

In my `.vimrc`, there is this line:

```
map <F4> :w<cr>:!python %<cr>
```

When I edit a python file using `vim /home/debian/rd.py` and press <kbd>F4</kbd> after the file was written, I get this error:

```
/bin/bash: /home/debian/rd.py: Permission denied
shell returned 126
Press ENTER or type command to continue
1 gphoto2  --get-all-files
1     0x670x700x680x6f0x740x6f0x320xc20xa00x200x2d0x2d0x670x650x740x2d0x610x6c0x6c0x2d0x660x690x6c0x650x730xa
2 gphoto2  --get-all-files
2 0x670x700x680x6f0x740x6f0x320x200x200x2d0x2d0x670x650x740x2d0x610x6c0x6c0x2d0x660x690x6c0x650x730xa

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

The result is right, why `Permission denied` and I get the result?

Edit:

I often  use `gphoto2  --get-all-files` to get the digital camera photos onto my pc, somedays the command 
`gphoto2  --get-all-files` can not run. I am confused by the phenomenon, when I erase it and input it again, it works. I pasted the two commands which look the same into a file, please download it from [here](http://s.yunio.com/6HBM7h)
and save it as `\tmp\compare.txt`,

Contents of file

```
gphoto2  --get-all-files
gphoto2  --get-all-files
```

When I open vim to write a small codes on python to see the reason,

The contents of rd.py

```
myfile=open("/tmp/compare.txt","rb")
for x,line in enumerate(myfile.readlines()):
   print  x+1,line,
   str1=""
   for char in line:
       str1=str1+hex(ord(char))
   print x+1,str1
```

press  <kbd>F4</kbd>  when I finished, I get the output, the reason is `&nbsp` in the command.

```
1      0x670x700x680x6f0x740x6f0x320xc20xa00x200x2d0x2d0x670x650x740x2d0x610x6c0x6c0x2d0x660x690x6c0x650x730xa    

2      0x670x700x680x6f0x740x6f0x320x200x200x2d0x2d0x670x650x740x2d0x610x6c0x6c0x2d0x660x690x6c0x650x730xa
```

str1 is `0xa0` which the `&nbsp` more than str2

Comment: do you get a permission denied when running from the terminal? are those the total contents of your script?

Comment: Do you get this for every python script you try to run?

Comment: I'm on ColdFusion side here, there's definitely something wrong with your python as your script should not be sent to bash directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you got permissions to write to `rd.py` for the existing login? I would suspect the `:w` fails as you do not have the write permission, but the next command `!python rd.py` runs, giving the result.

Try `$ sudo vim /home/debian/rd.py`and save inside vim

Another possibility is that executable bit is not set on  `rd.py`.

Comment: I do not believe the executable bit needs to be set of rd.py. Since the program that needs to be executable is python.

Answer (score 1):

From the look of that error message it seems that neither Vim nor Python are responsible for that problem. Also, your python script seems to call a fourth program, [gphoto2](http://gphoto.sourceforge.net/), so everything is a bit muddy at this point.

Without knowledge of the content of `rd.py` nobody here can *really* help you besides making wild speculations. I'd suggest you paste its content in your question or find a way to make it available for us.